# AngularJS ng-show IF AND condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<li ng-show="auth==true and user[0].auth==1">
```

What would be the proper way of writing the above? Both `auth` and `user[0].auth` are part of the `$rootScope`. I just want this list item to show when both `$rootScope.auth = true` and `$rootScope.user[0].auth = 1`

Comment: use `&&` instead of "and".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like bellow

```
<li ng-show="auth && user[0].auth==1">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li ng-show="auth==true && user[0].auth==1">
```